# Webview Crashes in Samsung Devices : Chrome 84

Tags: android, webview, crash, samsung-mobile

We are experiencing large number of crashes recently especially in Samsung devices (mostly Android 10, Chrome 84). The users start experiencing black screen/flickering screens while watching a video

The crash report in Play Console says : #00  pc 00000000017da494  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-m4ctAxSdd0tR94mcbW-sIA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so (offset 0x15b000)

Has anyone else been experiencing this and can anyone point out to what might be causing such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem too, and found chromium bug issue about this problem and waiting for bug fix.

You can check that bug issue on this page : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1109016

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have been following the issue and they have pushed a bug fix in their Canary version